# Android Studio textview配置ができない

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/simple-recyclerview-java/part-1-layouts-model-class

ここにある動画の4:14のあたりのように、マウスでtextviewをドラッグしても左上に戻ってしまうのですが、解決方法はありませんか?コードは全く同じなのですが・・・

Answer (score 0):

私の環境(Android Studio 3.6RC1/Linux)でご指摘のページにあるexample_item.xmlをコピーして動かしました少し古いコードですのでCardViewへの参照を最新版では`androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`へと変える必要がありますが、特にエディタの動作に支障は見られませんでした。以下の内容をご確認ください。

- imageViewは存在していますか? textViewから'layout_toEndOf'で正しく指定されていますか?
  このxmlではimageViewからの相対で指定してるようです。理解しやすくするためにはブループリントモードでxmlを操作したほうがわかりやすいです。(デザインモードでは指定しない限り画像が画面に表示されません、私が試したようにコピーアンドペーストしていただくのもいいと思います)
- 直接的な原因ではないと思いますが、ライブラリや、ビューへの参照は最新ですか？
  androidxへの移行のためサポートライブラリのクラス名は大きく入れ替わっています。